# Change size carousel when change orientation in sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, touch, orientation, carousel

I put my carousel in container item.

- In portrail mode, I set height 150, the images display fullscreen in carousel.
  But when I change to landscape orientation, there are two white blank in two side of images.
- I want change size carousel by setting another value of height. Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the orientationchange event
(http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.viewport.Default-event-orientationchange) and upon catching it call a function which will resize your container.

You can try something like this:

```
Ext.Viewport.on('orientationchange', 'handleOrientationChange', this);
```

Then in the handle function set your desired size of component:

```
handleOrientationChange: function(){
    Ext.getCmp('idOfMyContainer').setWidth('480px'); //or setHeight() depending on the real problem
}
```

You could also set the width and height according to the real size of screen, which you can get by calling these methods. Note that orientation change doesn't affect the return values of these so you would need to switch it manually:

```
Ext.Viewport.getWindowWidth();
Ext.Viewport.getWindowHeight()
```

Comment: you can use Ext.Viewport.getOrientation() to get the current orienation (portrait or landscape) and then update any components based on the new width/height of the Viewport